Using fpdf library creates a blank page
I get a blank page in the pdf-document, when I output a greater amount of text. I use the fpdf library. The following code (test code) is working well. When I add the commantary code I get a blank page.
The code is embedded in a wordpress CMS.
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$fileIncPath=getcwd();
require_once("$fileIncPath/wp-content/fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
$pdf->Text(40,50,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
$pdf->Text(40,60,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
$pdf->Text(40,70,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
$pdf->Text(40,80,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
$pdf->Text(40,90,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
//$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
//$pdf->Text(40,100,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10, true);
$pdf->Text(40,190,'Hallo Test auf Seite 1!', 0, 1);
$pdf->Output('I', 'test.pdf');
?>

I tested the code in a local environment only with php. This worked. On the server in a wordpress environment it didn't work.

SetFont() and Text() take only 3 parameters.

Make sure WordPress doesn't output any HTML before the PDF.

I think, that can't be the reason. Look at my source. When I have commentated one output, it works. Maybe there is puffer in wordpress? I corrected SetFont() and Text(). The mistake is the same.

When it works, try opening the PDF in a text editor to check what it contains.
